# Show only enabled item in v-treeview

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using v-treeview and i have items like that:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'name 1',
        disabled: false,
        children: [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'name 2',
                disabled: false,
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        name: 'name 3',
                        disabled: false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'name 4',
                disabled: false,
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 5,
                        name: 'name 5',
                        disabled: true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                name: 'name 6',
                disabled: true,
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 7,
                        name: 'name 7',
                        disabled: true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

that i want is, only showing the items with disabled false; without passing by filter data to send to v-treeview;

I already tried on slot on not showing any data when disabled is true but the the item set blank space:

```
<template v-slot:label="{item}" >
    <v-container v-if="!item.disabled">
          {{  item.name  }}
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Some items is provided with v-select, it allow to switch the disabled value of children items, so can't use filter computed cause i have no access of the children with disabled true;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `computed` in order to create a dynamic variable:

```
computed: {
  visibleElements: function() {
    // filter here only entries you are interested to show
    let visibleElements = elements.map(el => {
        :
        :
    });
    return visibleElements;
  }
}
```